# Why can't I get these cards to form a row. They are persistently falling into a column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

Here is the code I am using including the styling. It is a component for a React site, and for some reason I cannot get the cards to be evenly spaced in a row. I also will want to implement some breakpoints for smaller screen sizes but one that at a time unless anyone has ideas or reasons to do that first (I've heard from some coders to start with a small screen and work up.... any thoughts on that?) Let me know if there is anything else needed to figure out the issue and I appreciate and help in advance!

```
import React from "react";  

...

import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%", // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)",
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
  },
}));

export default function RecipeReviewCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
              R
            </Avatar>
          }
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="settings">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
          title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
          subheader="September 14, 2016"
        />
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
          title="Paella dish"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            This impressive...like.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton
            className={clsx(classes.expand, {
              [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
            })}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat 1/2 cup...10 minutes.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat oil...bring to a boil.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Add rice and ...don’t
              open.)
            </Typography>
            <Typography>
              Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then
              serve.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>

      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
              R
            </Avatar>
          }
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="settings">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
          title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
          subheader="September 14, 2016"
        />
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
          title="Paella dish"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            This impressive ... like.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton
            className={clsx(classes.expand, {
              [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
            })}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat 1/2 cup...10 minutes.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat oil ... to a boil.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Add rice...that don’t
              open.)
            </Typography>
            <Typography>
              Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then
              serve.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the display properties on the `<div>` wrapping your `<Card>` elements? Unless I'm missing something (and, obviously, will delete this post if I am), what shows here are the styes for rendering the Cards, but not so much for rendering them in relationship to each other/the container? So maybe working towards something like...

```
<div className="cardWrapper" style={ {
  display: flex, 
  flexDirection: row
  justifyContent: spaceAround } }>
   <Card />
   <Card />
   <Card />
</div>
```

Comment: I should note I got them in a row, but now need to work on making them responsive with breakpoints. Any suggestions for the most efficient way to do this? My approach would to change the number of cards per row and size of cards in corresponding breakpoints in my css file (not shown).